# Do online business LLCs have to foreign file in the state that the members live in?

Tags: florida, limited-liability-company

If I live in Florida and want to form my LLC in Wyoming for the better protections, will Florida still make me foreign file?

The business is entirely online and I will be renting a cheap, physical address in Wyoming from Northwest to receive all of my mail and act as the primary address.

Answer (score 1):

The place where the members of an LLC (i.e. its owners) live is irrelevant. Foreign filing is required in states where the company does business.

Also, the mere fact that a company receives mail at an address does not itself establish that this is where the company is doing business.

If the person or people who carry out the work of an LLC organized in Wyoming actually do the work in Florida, it should foreign file in Florida. It may also want to foreign file in places where it sells its online products to customers, especially if it is foreseeable that it might need to sue (e.g. for nonpayment) someone in a state where customers are located.

Comment: It's answers like this that make me thankful Australia decided to make corporations a Commonwealth responsibility

Comment: @DaleM There is a lot to be said for that. The benefits that the U.S. gets from having states as a "laboratory for Democracy" are rather overrated in the areas of corporate and commercial law.

Comment: Of course, Australia always wanted a stronger Federal government than the US demonstrated - the former was established by 19th century pragmatists rather than 18th century idealists. However, along with the telecommunications power, the corporations power has been the basis for the massive expansion of Federal lawmaking since the 1970s - most business is done by companies so that gives the Commonwealth an “in”.